# Failed to run a bootable USB

Tags: live-usb, yumi

**EDIT:** I tried to reinstall syslinux from "Misc Options", and I get an error. mtools crashed using this command: `mmove -D o -D O s:/ldlinux.sys s:/yumi/ldlinux.sys`.

---

This is what I've done until now:

1. attached my USB pen to PC
2. downloaded [GParted](http://gparted.org/download.php) Live ISO from stable directory
3. installed [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/#button) for Ubuntu, a program that allows you to create a bootable USB with multiple bootable ISOs
4. run `YUMI.gambas` from bash and entered my sudoer password
5. selected the USB pen and the ISO, and clicked "Create"
6. Checked that an `yumi` directory on the pen exists
7. Rebooted PC
8. pressed F8 at BIOS level and selected the pen

Result: USB bootloader was not started. On the contrary, my default bootloader started, and Linux booted. No error message was displayed. Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Do you mean Multisystem? I do not like it, it seems a quick-and-dirty port to Linux of a Windows program :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using UNetBootin

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Comment: I know unetbootin, but for what I know it doesn't allow you to boot more than one ISO

Answer (score -1):

There is also a very simple method

```
dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k
```

/dev/sbd is your usb

Comment: This surely is a ways to bring an image to a USB drive, but I'm not sure it is what OP wants. Although he/she doesn't spell it out explicitly, I think it's about multibooting from a flash drive. Anyways, this answer should at least contain some sort of explanation what the command does.